# Could not resolve this reference errors with .NET Framework and .NET Standard packages

Tags: .net

Thanks in advance.

I'm using VS 2017 / TFS 2012 on a Windows 2012 build server.
We have an internal repository for NuGet packages
The .sln I'm building is .NET Framework 4.6.2 but there is/are references to .netstandard packages
On the build server I've got:
.NET Core SDK 2.0.3
.NET Core SDK 2.1.202
.NET Core SDK 2.1.503,
a ton of .NET Framework 4.5.x - 4.6.2 SDKs, Multi-Targeting Packs
VS Enterprise 2017

When our VS2017 build errors out, the errors (there's many that are similar) we're seeing are this:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "BLoK.Rest.Sdk.Base, Version=3.0.22.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\Builds\214\Blok\WebUI\src\BLoKWeb\BLoK.Web.csproj]

The funny thing is, earlier in the build log I see this:
  Getting D:\Builds\214\BloK\WebUI\src\BLoKWeb\packages\BloK.Rest.Sdk.Base.3.0.22;C502066
  Getting D:\Builds\214\BloK\WebUI\src\BLoKWeb\packages\BloK.Rest.Sdk.Base.3.0.22\BLoK.Rest.Sdk.Base.3.0.22.nupkg;C502066
  Getting D:\Builds\214\BloK\WebUI\src\BLoKWeb\packages\BloK.Rest.Sdk.Base.3.0.22\lib;C502066
  Getting D:\Builds\214\BloK\WebUI\src\BLoKWeb\packages\BloK.Rest.Sdk.Base.3.0.22\lib\netstandard2.0;C502066
  Getting D:\Builds\214\BloK\WebUI\src\BLoKWeb\packages\BloK.Rest.Sdk.Base.3.0.22\lib\netstandard2.0\BLoK.Rest.Sdk.Base.dll;C502066
  Getting D:\Builds\214\BloK\WebUI\src\BLoKWeb\packages\BloK.Rest.Sdk.Base.3.0.22\lib\netstandard2.0\BLoK.Rest.Sdk.Base.pdb;C502066

I copied and pasted the paths above and sure enough, the BLoK.Rest.Sdk.Base.dll did exist where the build log said it did.  This confirmed the nuget package was in the \packages directory along with a bunch of other packages.  But in spite of this the build failed with "could not resolve this reference".

Our TFS build definition does a restore each time it runs.

If I manually download the missing BLoK.Rest.Sdk.Base.dll package and put it in an alternate location as specified in the build log, the build will get past this 
 error but fail on another package with, "Could not resolve this reference" but it'll point to .dll's in the GAC, like System.Web, for example.  How can a build not find System.Web?  Other builds don't have this problem but our newly developed BLoK project does.

Everything seems just fine - paths are valid, correct packages and package versions exist in the right locations, and yet the build failed even though the packages are in the \packages directory.  What am I missing here?  This is really problematic for us.  Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

K.J.

Comment: The integration of .netstandard and > net46 is *not* fantastic. Here is one thread about various problems: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/481 You might need "magic"; correct version of nuget package mangager, binding redirects in config files, edit package references in .csproj files etc

Comment: Take a look at this, if you've not done so: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/team-foundation-build